# How to find movie rating for 10 years when specific years are specified in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cut

I have a movie dataframe. I'm interested in the movie title, oscar year, and user rating columns. I need to sort it by the "Oscar Year" (in this column I have different years like 1926, 1927, 1928...2020). Then divide years into decades, and calculate the value "mean()" for this period.

Link to dataframe: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GUtF9oPmovlu2d6mtn5UbISXKB-B7S1r/view?usp=sharing

I tried a lot of ways, but since I'm a beginner, nothing worked for me

```
import pandas as pd
mv = pd.read_csv('data_1_7.csv')

# There was such data that is difficult to work with, so I deleted it using the method known to me (suggestions to resolve this issue are also gladly accepted)
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/28',"")
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/29',"")
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/30',"")
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/31',"")
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/32',"")
mv['Oscar Year']=mv['Oscar Year'].str.replace('/33',"")

mv['Oscar Year'].sort_values()

GroupByMean = mv.groupby('Oscar Year')[['IMDB Rating']].mean(numeric_only=True).reset_index() 
# so I got the data by year, but not by decade

mv['Oscar Year'] = mv['Oscar Year'].astype('int')
Rating10['Bins'] = pd.cut(mv['Oscar Year'], bins = 10, precision=0).unique()
Rating10['Rating'] = mv['IMDB Rating'] 
# received invalid data
```

I tried several other ways but all in vain
I need your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division and multiplication to round down the year to the nearest multiple of 10 to obtain the decade. The rest is still the same as your code with `groupby_mean`:

```
# str[:4] extracts the first 4 characters of Oscar Year
mv['Oscar Year'] = mv['Oscar Year'].str[:4].astype(int)

decade =  mv['Oscar Year'] // 10 * 10
ratings = mv['IMDB Rating'].groupby(decade).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> ratings
    Oscar Year  IMDB Rating
0         1920     6.707692
1         1930     7.198851
2         1940     7.572857
3         1950     7.502000
4         1960     7.578000
5         1970     7.766000
6         1980     7.532000
7         1990     7.860000
8         2000     7.727273
9         2010     7.744318
10        2020     7.587500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data_1_7.csv")

# Extract the decade from the "Oscar Year" column and create a new column "Decade"
df['Decade'] = df['Oscar Year'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:3] + "0s")

# Group the dataframe by "Decade" and calculate the mean of the "IMDB Rating" column
df_decade_mean = df.groupby('Decade')['IMDB Rating'].mean().reset_index()

# Sort the resulting dataframe by "Oscar Year" column
df_decade_mean = df_decade_mean.sort_values(by='Decade')

# Display the resulting dataframe
print(df_decade_mean)
```

Output:

```
   Decade  IMDB Rating
0   1920s     6.707692
1   1930s     7.198851
2   1940s     7.572857
3   1950s     7.502000
4   1960s     7.578000
5   1970s     7.766000
6   1980s     7.532000
7   1990s     7.860000
8   2000s     7.727273
9   2010s     7.744318
10  2020s     7.587500
```

Comment: The idea is good but don't use `apply` when you can use vectorization.